# SQL (simply) Join two tables row by row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanna join 2 tables row by row, meaning if i have two tables A,B i want:
 row 1 of A to join only row 1 of B
 row 2 of A to join only row 2 of B 
etc.

so if i had

```
table A
name

John
George
Nick
Legolas



table B
surname

Smith
Rogueman
Born
Yohazol


the result would be:

table C
name    surname


John    Smith
George  Rogueman
Nick    Born
Legolas Yohazol
```

thanks in advance

Comment: someone is outsourcing their homework. as far i as know we correct issues and not answer your homework

Comment: To do this you will need to match the rows by using an id column or similar. Add id columns to your tables, then join them using an INNER JOIN

Comment: @Haloha, you don't have any column to relate the tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this..

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (), *
  FROM tbl1
  -- ORDER BY id (or whatever you're ordering by)
) AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (), *
  FROM tbl2
  -- ORDER BY id (or whatever you're ordering by)
) AS t2
  USING (row_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an `id` or any column to match the rows, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` as an id.

```
WITH cteA(rn, name) AS(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,
        name
    FROM tableA
),
cteB(rn, name) AS(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,
        name
    FROM tableB
)
SELECT
    a.name AS name,
    b.name AS surname
FROM cteA a
INNER JOIN cteB b
    ON b.rn = a.rn
```

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` is not needed at ll. You can have `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` in Postgres, if you don't care for the order